# How to use Razor instead Jquery ajax to get data from a function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I never use **Razor** in *asp.net MVC* so I really don't know how it works.
Every time I want to tag a function in my *Controller* I use *jquery ajax* and I write very *javascript* code and my projects are very messy.
Now I want to make something different.

I have controller named as `HomeController` where I get data from *Sql Server Database*, using *model entity* for that.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult getClasses()
    {
        IList<Class> classes = (from x in db.Class select x).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(classes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public JsonResult getTypes(string className)
    {
        IList<String> allTypes = (from type in db.Type
                                  where type.class_name == className
                                  orderby type.type_name
                                  select type.type_name).Distinct().ToList();
       return Json(allTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

And I have master.page *(named as SiteMaster)* where I get this data through *jquery ajax*.

```
<body>
 <div id="header">
   <ul class="classesName"></ul>
 </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/getClasses",
            type: "GET",
            data: {},
            success: function (result) {
                for (n = 0; n < result.length; n++) {
                    $('.classesName').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="showTypes( \'' + result[n].class_name + '\')" >' + result[n].class_name + '</a></li>');
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

I have another *ajax* for getting the *Types* when some *Class* is clicked..but all this I want to change so I can use ***@Razor***.

All I want is to show the data from `getClasses()` into the *masterPage* and when some *Class* is clicked, to send that argument into `getTypes(string className)` but **without** using *javascript* and **use** ***@Razor***.
So my question is can I do this and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part (sending the result of `getClasses()` to your view) can be done with Razor alone, because all of that work *can be done on the server*.

It is important to understand that the primary strength of Razor is that it allows you to perform (almost, if not) any C# on your views. So doing what you want can be as simple as writing the code as if you were coding in C#:

```
@{
    // I'd suggest you refactor your code to have your `getClasses()` function
    // readily available somewhere that's not a controller
    var classes = Data.getClasses();
}
<div id="header">
    <ul class="classesName">
        @foreach (var clazz in classes) {
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="showTypes('@clazz')">@clazz</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

For the second part (getting the `Types` when the link is clicked), you're out of luck. The click has to happen on the client, so by then your C# would have been evaluated, the HTML flushed, and the time for your Razor to run would have come and gone. If those types aren't cached on the page somehow, you'll have to make a request against the server again (and AJAX is one way to do that).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ajax to load the initial master page, just return a view containing all the class data you need to display as that saves you the extra trip to the server. As for getting the data when a class is clicked that is an ideal place to use Ajax and to do that in Razor you would use one of the many @Ajax.xxx helpers (@Ajax.RawActionLink, @Ajax.BeginForm, etc.). The following link might be a good place to start looking at how views are used in asp.net MVC [views tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)